# Ruby on Rails - Bad interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundle, gemset

I'm facing a weird issue here. When I create a `gemset` using `rvm`, the path of `which rails` changes. Following are commands I'm running on terminal. I referred related question on SO, but didn't help me much.

```
someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247

someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ which ruby
/home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ which rails
/home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
```

---

```
someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ rvm gemset use some_app (I also tried rvm gemset use 2.0.0@some_app --create)
Using ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset some_app

someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ which ruby
/home/someuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails (<--- the path changed!)
```

---

`rails s` or `bundle` command gives error:

```
someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ rails s
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

---

I've to run following command to fix the path:

```
someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ rvm use 2.0.0
Using /home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247

someuser@ubuntu-laptop:~/sandbox/some_app$ which rails
/home/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
```

I've following entry in `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Why is it happening? How can I fix this, so the path won't change on change/creation of gemset?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you previously would have installed rails using

`sudo apt get install rails`.

`which rails` returns the first occurence of `rails` in the path.

Try this - Remove the native rails first by doing `sudo apt-get remove rails`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. Got `Package 'rails' is not installed, so not removed`.

Comment: I think you would be having a file named `/usr/local/bin/rails`. Can you try to remove that and check again?

Comment: Not sure how's that gonna help, but I tried and it didn't help.